# How to identify exponential growth within an array of integer data?

Tags: arrays, math, functional-programming, exponential

For example if I have an array with integers in an accending order - var intArray = [2, 6, 7, 10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 140, 200, 202, 207, 213, 215]

How to write a function, that will identify the beginning of exponential growth, that starts with the integer 10, and ends with the integer 200? In other words, how to write a function that recognizes the start of the growth and the start of the decay within the array?

Okay, I'm getting answers about not stating a correct exponential growth. That is not the case.
The main thing I want to find out - How to find the moment when integer values extremely increase and decrease?

Comment: Have you considered mapping natural log over the array and then identify the start of the linear growth?

Comment: What is your criteria for "exponential growth"? If you ask me, [10,30,50,70,90] isn't exponential, it's linear.

Comment: ok, my mistake. That is in fact linear, but that doesn't change the question. How do I spot the range from 90 to 200?

Comment: Jonny, I didn't quite understand. You're saying I have to find exp(i) for every int in the array? Okei, let's presume I've done that. Then what do I have to do?

Comment: The data does not particularly resemble an exponential curve. Are you trying to fit a logistic curve into it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function Or perhaps the error function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function ?

Comment: What does "extremely increase and decrease" mean?

Comment: For example - integers in accending order - 1,2,3,4,6,10,150,250,1250,500,300,150,50,49,48,47,45,44
As we can see, starting from number 10, the numbers start to increase rapidly. I need a function that identifies, at which point (in this case 10) the increase begins.

Comment: Find the datapoint that has the largest ratio with the preceding datapoint? This question can't really be answered unless you give a precise definition of what you're looking for. So, you're not looking to fit a statistical model to the data? Maybe you could fit some model to a subset or window and then pick the window with highest correlation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function grows exponentially, the log of the function grows linearly.

Here is your data:

```
[2, 6, 7, 10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 140, 200, 202, 207, 213, 215]
```

Here is the log of your data:

```
[0.693147, 1.79176,  1.94591,  2.30259,  3.4012,  3.91202,  4.2485,
 4.49981,  4.94164,  5.29832,  5.30827,  5.33272, 5.36129,  5.37064]
```

You can see a plot of the log data here: [Wolfram Alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+log%28%5B2%2C+6%2C+7%2C+10%2C+30%2C+50%2C+70%2C+90%2C+140%2C+200%2C+202%2C+207%2C+213%2C+215%5D%29)

Notice that between the 5th and 10th items the plot increases linearly. In this region, the values are growing exponentially.  If you want to be more lenient, you might say it increases roughly exponentially between the 1st and 10th items.

You haven't been very precise in exactly how you want to characterize "the start of exponential growth" so I won't say more unless you clarify.